# How to apply the animation with the for loop in the element?

Tags: css, css-animations, nuxt.js

I am trying to animate this on page load. I tried many ways but eighter the animation happing all at once for all the elements or not happing at all .

I also tried the vue transition-group but the v-on:enter doesn't work with nuxt.
The major issue is how to get it working on load of the page.

This is the link how it should work [click this codepen link](https://codepen.io/shrishankit/pen/GRgEwed)

```
    <template>
      <div class="greybackground" style="height:100vh">
        <div class="exprience">
          <div class="aboutme">
        <span class="firsttext title is-1">Experience</span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <p class="intro textwhite">
          I'm the co-founder of Gruntwork, a company that helps startups get up
          and running on AWS with DevOps best practices and world-class
          infrastructure. Our mission is to make it an order of magnitude easier
          to understand, develop, and deploy software. We take care of all the
          "undifferentiated heavy lifting"—the grunt work—so that your team can
          focus on the products and services unique to your company.
        </p>
          </div>
          <div class="onend">
        <div class="wrapperprogbox">
          <h3>Language I speak</h3>

          <div class="content">
            <div class="progbargroup">
              <div>
            <!-- <transition-group name="list" tag="p"> -->
              <span
                class="proglist"
                v-for="(item, index) in langs"
                :key="index"
                :item.sync="langs"
              >
                <div class="slideInLeft">
                  <div class="progbar">
                    <span class="textwhite ">{{ item.langname }}</span>
                    <transition name="slide-left" tag="p">
                    <progress

                      class="progress is-small is-primary progbartitle "
                      :value="item.score"
                      max="100"
                      >15%</progress
                    >
                    </transition>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </span>
            <!-- </transition-group> -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    // import progbar from "../components/progbar";
    import { FadeTransition } from "vue2-transitions";
    import Velocity from "velocity-animate";
    export default {
      components: {

        FadeTransition
      },

      data() {
        return {
          //   langs: ["Golang", "JavaScript", "TypeScript", "HTML", "CSS"],
          show: false,
          // displayList:false,
          style: { enter: 300, leave: 300 },
          langs: [
        { langname: "Golang", score: "63" },
        { langname: "JavaScript", score: "90" },
        { langname: "TypeScript", score: "34" },
        { langname: "HTML", score: "88" },
        { langname: "CSS", score: "65" }
          ]
        };
      },
      mounted() {
        this.init();

        this.$nuxt.$on("STAG_ANIMATE", this.AnimateDelayList());
      },
      methods: {
        init() {
          this.show = true;
          // this.enter();
          this.AnimateDelayList();
        },
        AnimateDelayList() {
          // get vendor transition property
          this.displayList = true;
          var items = document.querySelectorAll(".proglist");

          var docElemStyle = document.documentElement.style;
          var transitionProp =
        typeof docElemStyle.transition == "string"
          ? "transition"
          : "WebkitTransition";

          console.log("Style element", docElemStyle, transitionProp, items);

          for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        // stagger transition with transitionDelay
        item.style[transitionProp + "Delay"] = i * 50 + "ms";
        console.log("this is i", i);

        // item.classList.toggle("is-moved");
          }
        },
      }
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Why not just do it with CSS like the codepen you linked?

Comment: that's just hard coding. I want to make a component so that I can use it anywhere. @thingEvery